# sencha touch microloader not working in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I created a sencha touch 2/phonegap app that works fine on android, and needed to put it into iOS.

I successfully did so, then made a small code change (changed a card animation from left to right) and the app stopped loading.

The index.html comes up, but it's like the microloader is not being called. None of the ST javascript is executed.

I've tried creating a fresh iPhone app in XCode, I've ensured I have the Mac phonegap file referenced, I've checked that the microloader and all the files in the app.json exist. Apart from referencing the Mac phonegap file instead of the Android one the entire directory structure is copied verbatim,  but I can't get it to run and XCode isn't giving me any error message.

Yet it DID successfully run before I made an irrelevant change. Of course I've tried changing the code back, but that did nothing.

Here's my index.html. As you can see it's pretty bare bones:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script> 
    <script src="sencha-touch-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="./microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
    <body  style="background: url(splash.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;" >

    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I tried creating a new iPhone app, I hadn't tried deleting my web app and copying everything across again. That worked, I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should include cordova and sencha scripts in app.json. So far I know it is recommended to include just little microloader script in index.html.

Answer (score -2):

It seems microloader is bugged, as of 2.0.0-beta3.

It generates different syntax errors for different projects when it tries to apply diffs for .js files - that's why first run is successful, and later ones not, regardless of code changes.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the askers question.  Please provide a solution.